# Preventing Linux Kernel from killing Java process with really large heap

Tags: java, linux, memory, kill-process

Running  Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS with 32 cores 244GB. Its the Amazon EC2 memory instance the big one and Java 1.7u25

My java process is running with -Xmx226g

I'm trying to create a really large local cache using CQEngine and so far its blazingly fast with 30,000,000 records. Of course I will add an eviction policy that will allow garbage collection to clean up old objects evicted, but really trying to push the limits here :)

When looking at jvisualvm, the total heap is at about 180GB which dies 40GB to soon. I should be able to squeeze out a bit more.

Not that I don't want the kernel to kill a process if it runs out of resources but I think it's killing it to early and want to squeeze the mem usage as much as possible.

The ulimit output is as follows...

```
ubuntu@ip-10-156-243-111:/var/log$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1967992
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1967992
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The kern.log output is...

```
340 total pagecache pages
0 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
63999984 pages RAM
1022168 pages reserved
649 pages shared
62830686 pages non-shared
[ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
[  505]     0   505     4342       93   9       0             0 upstart-udev-br
[  507]     0   507     5456      198   2     -17         -1000 udevd
[  642]     0   642     5402      155  28     -17         -1000 udevd
[  643]     0   643     5402      155  29     -17         -1000 udevd
[  739]     0   739     3798       49  10       0             0 upstart-socket-
[  775]     0   775     1817      124  25       0             0 dhclient3
[  897]     0   897    12509      152  10     -17         -1000 sshd
[  949]   101   949    63430       91   9       0             0 rsyslogd
[  990]   102   990     5985       90   8       0             0 dbus-daemon
[ 1017]     0  1017     3627       40   9       0             0 getty
[ 1024]     0  1024     3627       41  10       0             0 getty
[ 1029]     0  1029     3627       43   6       0             0 getty
[ 1030]     0  1030     3627       41   3       0             0 getty
[ 1032]     0  1032     3627       41   1       0             0 getty
[ 1035]     0  1035     1083       34   1       0             0 acpid
[ 1036]     0  1036     4779       49   5       0             0 cron
[ 1037]     0  1037     4228       40   8       0             0 atd
[ 1045]     0  1045     3996       57   3       0             0 irqbalance
[ 1084]     0  1084     3627       43   2       0             0 getty
[ 1085]     0  1085     3189       39  11       0             0 getty
[ 1087]   103  1087    46916      300   0       0             0 whoopsie
[ 1159]     0  1159    20490      215   0       0             0 sshd
[ 1162]     0  1162  1063575      263  15       0             0 console-kit-dae
[ 1229]     0  1229    46648      153   4       0             0 polkitd
[ 1318]  1000  1318    20490      211  10       0             0 sshd
[ 1319]  1000  1319     6240     1448   1       0             0 bash
[ 1816]  1000  1816 70102543 62010032   4       0             0 java
[ 1947]     0  1947    20490      214   6       0             0 sshd
[ 2035]  1000  2035    20490      210   0       0             0 sshd
[ 2036]  1000  2036     6238     1444  13       0             0 bash
[ 2179]  1000  2179    13262      463   2       0             0 vi
Out of memory: Kill process 1816 (java) score 987 or sacrifice child
Killed process 1816 (java) total-vm:280410172kB, anon-rss:248040128kB, file-rss:0kB
```

The kern.log clearly states that it killed my process because it ran out of memory. But like I said I think I can squeeze it a bit more. Is there any settings I need to do to allow me to use the 226GB allocated to JAVA.

Comment: Which JVM are you Using? How many processors or cores does your system have? Do you have NUMA enabled in Linux kernel?

Comment: I edited my question with the details... As for NUMA... I don't know...

Comment: JVM consumes more memory that only heap. It needs some memory for its overhead. Use distributed cache and not so big heap. I wondering how long is major garage collection :). BTW: do you use huge pages?

Comment: With G1 GC it seems to be ok only a few milliseconds. Large pages? Ill try ;) Distributed cache = to expenssive to implement right now... But out of -Xmx226g how much does the vm need? Keep in mind linux kills it at 180GB

Comment: I think it could be relevant for Java devs. Especially when they need to tuned for large memory usage.